# iOS app posting to facebook but via link is not found

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to figure out where I set the redirect for when a user clicks "via app" after someone post with my app. Right now when I click on my via [link](https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=318721611552813) it tells me that the page is not found. I would like to set this link to the Facebook page I made for my app.

I have checked all the setting at my developers.facebook.com. I am thinking it is something set inside the graph api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create a page for my app. That is where it was trying to redirect to. You can create/set your page in App Details.